# How can I make my python program faster? CSES Exercise

Tags: python

So I am trying to solve this CSES exercise : https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1621/

[Here is the screenshot of the exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ43P.png)

And here is my code :

```
n = int(input())
input_line = input()

integers = list(map(int, input_line.split()))


while len(integers) != 0:
    integers = [element for element in integers if element != integers[0]]
    count= count + 1

print(count)
```

My code has exceeded the time limit for many tests (the tests where there was a large amount of data to process).

I tried to optimise my code but nothing worked, it is too slow,

Comment: `print(len(set(integers)))` - your solution is simply *terribly* inefficient because of O(n^2) vs. the set-solution in O(n).

Comment: Consider how you might do this yourself without a computer.  You probably wouldn't take each number, scan the rest of the list, and then keep doing this over and over.  What might you do if you had all these numbers on pieces of paper instead to try to figure out how many of them are distinct?

Comment: It would be better to add the problem statement directly in the question instead of links since links can expire or change causing the question to be rendered ineffective.

Comment: Refer [help] on asking good questions. [edit] your question to include what you've tried so far to fix the problem, even if it didn't help

Comment: It's slow because you're iterating over the list multiple times, creating a new smaller list, and repeating until there are no more items remaining.  Creating all those lists takes _time_.  How in the world did you come up with this approach?!

Comment: @Max actually, that's probably exactly what you'd do if you had to do this on paper.  Humans aren't as good at making use of indices as machines are.

Comment: @Cubic What I was getting at is that I would sort them (probably a loose near-sort as as a human)

Comment: Okay, using sets is way more efficient and quick for this case, sorry I'm not that good in python, I am trying to learn

Comment: @MehdiElMaaroufi - no need to feel sorry.  Just try to include more clear Prob. description and "the steps that you've tried" to improve.   Let's know how it goes finally...

Answer (score 1):

You're needlessly parsing strings and constantly constructing new lists when you should be using sets, which automatically deduplicate data into distinct values

```
# discard first line, since not necessary unless doing input validation
_ = input()
# print the length of distinct space separated strings in the second line 
print(len(set(input().split())))
```